# Exposing C++ to C# in Mono: invalid conversion of function?

Tags: c#, c++, mono, cil, void

I'm writing a plugin system by embedding Mono into my C++ program for Windows.
Right now I'm trying to expose a C++ function to the C# runtime so that the scripts can call C++ functions from the main program.

This is done like so:

```
   mono_add_internal_call("Hello::MonoMsg",MonoMsg);
```

I have all but cooked copypasta of two examples and both suffer the same error:

```
C:\Projects\MonoTestBed\main.cpp|34|error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(MonoString*)' to 'const void*'|
C:\Projects\MonoTestBed\main.cpp|34|error:   initializing argument 2 of 'void mono_add_internal_call(const char*, const void*)'|
```

Now, I have found one person's post about this /somewhere/, but I didn't find a solution, only a way to get it to compile - cast the MonoMsg as (void*)MonoMsg. That would get it to compile, but then it would break, crash kerblam, when you run it - it'd report that the function could not be found.

Here is the relevant code and includes just in case you want that too.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

#include<mono/jit/jit.h>
#include<mono/metadata/assembly.h>
#include <mono/metadata/mono-config.h>
#include <mono/metadata/mono-debug.h>
#include <mono/metadata/debug-helpers.h>
#include <mono/metadata/appdomain.h>
#include <mono/metadata/object.h>
#include <mono/metadata/threads.h>
#include <mono/metadata/environment.h>
#include <mono/metadata/mono-gc.h>
using namespace std;

 __declspec(dllexport) void MonoMsg(MonoString *msg)
{
        cout<<msg;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
//    mono_set_dirs(NULL,NULL);

//    mono_config_parse(NULL);

    MonoDomain *domain = mono_jit_init("C:\\herro.exe");

    MonoAssembly *assembly= mono_domain_assembly_open(domain,"C:\\herro.exe");
    cout<<assembly;
    //mono_jit_exec(domain,assembly,0,NULL);

    mono_add_internal_call("Hello::MonoMsg",MonoMsg);

    . . .
```

> EDIT: I almost forgot to mention that this is some kind of, erm, P/invoke approach? or something. :

Answer (score 1):

The changes needed to make your code work:

1. the `argv` argument of `main` is `char**`
2. you should pass `argc` and `argv` to `mono_jit_exec`
3. you should add the internal call **before** you invoke `mono_jit_exec`

Something like this:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MonoDomain *domain = mono_jit_init("C:\\herro.exe");

    MonoAssembly *assembly= mono_domain_assembly_open(domain,"C:\\herro.exe");
    cout<<assembly;

    mono_add_internal_call("Hello::MonoMsg",MonoMsg);
    mono_jit_exec(domain,assembly,argc,argv);
```

Comment: still fails for me

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify the namespace.  Assuming you compiled the `Hello` class within the `YourAssembly` namespace, the following correction will fix it.

`mono_add_internal_call("YourAssembly.Hello::MonoMsg",MonoMsg);`